# easier way to do multiple substr instr OR statements oracle pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr

I want to check every 2 positions of a table column for many different values. (selecting any row that matches any specified value in any of the 2 digit positions)
This is the only way I know of to do what I need, but I bet there is a cleaner, shorter way:

```
select *
from table
where 1=1
and (      
Substr(columnA,1,2)  IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,3,2)  IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,5,2)  IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,7,2)  IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,9,2)  IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,11,2) IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,12,2) IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,14,2) IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
                        or Substr(columnA,16,2) IN ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM') )
;
```

note: if the column's value is ABCDEF, and we are checking for 'BC', this should not find a match, only 'AB', 'CD', 'EF' should match.

I want to be able to list everything I am searching for just once. Even better would be to only list columnA once.
I did find an INSTR function that may be useful, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

this works:
Instr(columnA,'XX') IN (1,3,5,7,9,11,14,16)

But is there a better way than to do this for every value I am searching for?
Could I use COALESCE some how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) to match a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)? Something like that:

```
'^(..)*((CE)|(44)|(45)|(87)|(89)|(UT)|(AZ)|(XX)|(YY)|(S1)|(S2)|(S3)|(S4)|(ES)|(PM))'
```

- `^` ensure the regex is anchored to the start of line
- `(..)*` eats 0 to many *pair* of characters
- `((CE)|...)` matches one of your digraphs.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38453/0 for a live example.

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors. 
would I put something like this in my select:
 AND REGEXP(columnA, '^(..)*(CE)|(44)|(45)|(87)|(89)|(UT)|(AZ)|(XX)|(YY)|(S1)|(S2)|(S3)|(S4)|(ES)|(PM)')
?

Comment: that seems to be working !!
I needed to use the regexp_like and i didn't have the parenthesis right

Comment: How would I do the inverse of this? regexp_notlike equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you intend to search every 2 characters. I am assuming the even numbered starting numbers are incorrect: technically you are searching overlapping strings in the original question.

Since this is a regular pattern , you can generate it, which can help you simplify the query.

```
WITH search_pattern AS
        (SELECT     LEVEL * 2 - 1 search_start
         FROM       DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9)
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM   table1 t CROSS JOIN search_pattern sp
WHERE  SUBSTR (t.columna, search_start, 2) IN 
          ('CE','44','45','87','89','UT','AZ','XX','YY','S1','S2','S3','S4','ES','PM')
```

In this case, we have one row for each position, which is functionally equivalent to `or`. The `distinct` keyword is necessary to prevent rows that qualify more than once from being returned more than once.

---

While this solution is functional, @SylvainLeroux's answer using regex will likely perform better.

Comment: this seems like it would also work. How would I combine this CTE with my basic query that just selects distinct names that have those codes in columnA?

Comment: Just use the list of columns you want returned instead of `t.*`. The CTE works just like a table: if you don't specify it's columns in the `SELECT` clause, they won't be returned.

Comment: I got this to work as well, but it is a bit harder to type and copy and past around to various queries. I don't have enough reputation to up either of these answers.